# PHP PDO binding problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, I think that I've tried everything and read allot but I can't seem to find any solution. I'm trying to create a script that opens an XML file and reads it to my database. I found out about the PHP PDO so I decided to try and use that, but it's killing me.

I'm creating the following database table:

```
$sql = "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eve_market_data;
CREATE TABLE eve_market_data
(
    `order` INT NOT NULL,
    `region` INT NOT NULL,
    `station` INT NOT NULL,
    `range` INT,
    `price` FLOAT(12,2) NOT NULL,
    `vol_remain` INT,
    `min_volume` INT,
    `expires_date` DATE,
    `reported_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `sell` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
```

The following query should be sufficient to load the data into the database (as far as my knowledge goes):

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `eve_market_data` 
(`order`, `region`, `station`, `range`, `price`, `vol_remain`, `min_volume`, `expires_date`, `reported_time`,`sell`)
VALUES
(
    :orderid,
    :regionid,
    :stationid,
    :range,
    :price,
    :volremain,
    :minvolume,
    :expires,
    :reportedtime,
    :sell
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `range` = :range,
    `price` = :price,
    `vol_remain` = :volremain,
    `min_volume` = :minvolume,
    `expires_date` = :expires,
    `reported_time` = :reportedtime
;";
```

Then the following code should be loading it up to the db:

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $so->order ); $i++ )
{
$order = $so->order[$i];

echo "[{$i}] Inserting... " . $order['id'];

$sth->bindParam(':orderid', $orderid = (int) $order['id']);
$sth->bindParam(':regionid', $regionid = (int) $order->region);
$sth->bindParam(':stationid', $stationid = (int) $order->station);
$sth->bindParam(':range', $range = (int) $order->range);
$sth->bindParam(':price', $price = (float) $order->price);
$sth->bindParam(':volremain', $volremain = (int) $order->vol_remain);
$sth->bindParam(':minvolume', $minvolume = (int) $order->min_volume);
$sth->bindParam(':expires', $expires = (string) $order->expires);
$sth->bindParam(':reportedtime', $reporttime = date('Y') . "-" . (string) $order->reported_time);
$sth->bindParam(':sell', $sell = 1);

if( $sth->execute() ) echo '<br/>Executed';

echo "<br/><br/>";

if( $i === 7 ) break;
}
```

But for some reason the order ID remains the same for each query. I've tested this by removing the 'on duplicate' statement and it reveals this error for each time the query is executed:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' in ***/ECProcessor.php on line 65

I have checked the parameters over and over and as seen in the code it actually echo's the order id, so I'm absolutely sure the order id is changing. Other parameters seem to change just fine and the resulting row has all the other data that the last XML 'row' does except for the order id.

Does anybody know what the problem is / might be? Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

> @deceze 2147483647 is coincidentally the highest possible number of a 32 bit integer. I'd guess you're trying to store a number larger than that and it maxes out there.

Comment: 2147483647 is coincidentally the highest possible number of a 32 bit integer. I'd guess you're trying to store a number larger than that and it maxes out there.

Comment: @deceze ding ding ding. @Swahjak, change your column type for `order` to `bigint`

Comment: gah didn't even notice that :)

Comment: @deceze That was indeed the problem UNSIGNED fixed the problem (for now). Thanks.

Comment: You should first create an array with all fields names and use it for both to create  the db and bindParam. Loop across it to use index num for bindParam using  ? Param In your prepared stmt. Make sure add (int) $so->$order.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);

$sth->bindParam(':orderid', $orderid);
$sth->bindParam(':regionid', $regionid);
$sth->bindParam(':stationid', $stationid);
$sth->bindParam(':range', $range);
$sth->bindParam(':price', $price);
$sth->bindParam(':volremain', $volremain);
$sth->bindParam(':minvolume', $minvolume);
$sth->bindParam(':expires', $expires);
$sth->bindParam(':reportedtime', $reporttime);
$sth->bindParam(':sell', $sell);

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $so->order ); $i++ ) {
    $order = $so->order[$i];
    echo "[{$i}] Inserting... " . $order['id'];

    $orderid = (int) $order['id'];
    $regionid = (int) $order->region;
    $stationid = (int) $order->station;
    $range = (int) $order->range;
    $price = (float) $order->price;
    $volremain = (int) $order->vol_remain;
    $minvolume = (int) $order->min_volume;
    $expires = (string) $order->expires;
    $reporttime = date('Y') . "-" . (string) $order->reported_time;
    $sell = 1;

    try {
        $sth->execute();
        echo "executed successfully <br />";
    catch Exception $e) {
        die("Oh noes! There's an error in the query!<br />");
    }
}
```

Something like this perhaps bind the params outside of the loop then just assign the variables inside the loop.